# Couldn't open wallet: wrong device status: 0x6a30 (UNKNOWN) EXPECTED 0x9000 (SW_OK) MASK 0xffff

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I cannot open the wallet anymore on my Ledger Nano S. Ledger is working fine with other crypto.
Every this failure:
Couldn't open wallet: wrong device status: 0x6a30 (UNKNOWN) EXPECTED 0x9000 (SW_OK) MASK 0xffff
I installed the latest version of GUI Wallet 0.17.2.1
and I am using the Monero app version 1.7.4 on my Ledger